# Use Global variable in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-services

I have to use global variable in angular service.

I have function to get session id from parent application. like this

```
var sessionID;

function AddSessionID(e) {
    sessionId = e;
}
```

This is the function I have used for get sessionid and this function called in parent app.

I need to use this session id(sessionID) inside angular service as a parameter.

this is my service call

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    mApp.service('compasService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    //Public API
    return {
        initialLayout: initialLayout
    };

    function initialLayout() {
        var dataObj = {};
        dataObj.command = 'getLayoutCstics';
        dataObj.sessionID = sessionId;
        dataObj.userid = userID;
        var transform = function (data) {
            return $.param(dataObj);
        },
        request = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: myURL,
            //params:For passing via query string
            transformRequest: transform,
            dataType: "text",
            //To explicitly remove a header automatically added via $httpProvider.defaults.headers on a per request basis
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            crossDomain: true
        });

        return (request.then(successHandler, erroHandler));
    }

})();
```

Please get me a proper way to get it.

Comment: Where is exactly your sessionID ? Is it a service ?

Comment: How exactly is sessionID a global variable?  It looks like you might be declaring it within a scope.  In addition, why wouldn't you just maintain that variable as part of the singleton instance of the service?

Comment: I think his point is that this `sessionID` is a global variable already. The value is set some place else in the application out of the scope of the Angular JS service.

Comment: Is the `sessionID` a global variable in the same window or frame as your Angular service, or by "parent application" do you also mean a "parent frame"?

Comment: @GregBurghardt fair enough, although that's hardly clear from the question :)

Comment: If it is truly a global variable it is accessible anywhere in your app. Angular is javascript and all normal javascript scoping rules apply

Answer (score 1):

Architectually speaking, if you must use global variables, you want to limit the places that must use the global context. In this case, you might benefit from a `sessionService` in Angular that encapsulates access to the session Id.

```
(function(global) {
    'use strict';

    mApp.service("sessionService", function() {
        return {
            getSessionID: function() {
                return global.sessionId;
            },
            getUserID: function() {
                return global.userID;
            }
        };
    });
}(this));
```

Then you can specify that as a dependency in your other Angular services:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    mApp.service('compasService', ['$http', '$q', 'sessionService', function ($http, $q, sessionService) {

    //Public API
    return {
        initialLayout: initialLayout
    };

    function initialLayout() {
        var dataObj = {
                command: 'getLayoutCstics',
                sessionID: sessionService.getSessionID(),
                userId: sessionService.getUserID()
            },
            transform = function (data) {
                return $.param(dataObj);
            },
            request = $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: myURL,
                //params:For passing via query string
                transformRequest: transform,
                dataType: "text",
                //To explicitly remove a header automatically added via $httpProvider.defaults.headers on a per request basis
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                },
                crossDomain: true
            });

        return (request.then(successHandler, erroHandler));
    }

})();
```

The `successHandler` and `erroHandler` appear to be global functions as well. The second function, `erroHandler` appears to be misspelled and should be `errorHandler` (notice the "r" before the "H"), though I don't know if the spelling is an actual problem.

The whole point is to encapsulate access to global variables in one or more services so you limit your use of globals in your other services, modules and controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. But I have to use the same function name (AddSessionID) to get the value. How to use with same function name.
function AddSessionID(e) {
    sessionId = e;
}

Comment: You can't use AddSessionID to get the value. The source code for that function sets the value.